# Datatable returns all the data when server side is set to true

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have the following code where I want to use server side to lazy load my data. My goal is to display 10 records per page. The rest of the data should be loaded as and when the user clicks on a particular page.

What's happening now is that the datatable displays all the records at once. Can someone help me fix this issue?

```
  var table = $("#members").DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,               
            paging: true,
            "pagingType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": "10",
            "length": "10",

            ajax: {
                url: "/api/members",
                dataSrc: "",

            },

            columns: [
                {
                    data: "cardNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "registrationDate",

                },
                {
                    data: "fullName",

                },
                {
                    data: "address"
                },
                {
                    data: "phoneNumber"
                },
                {
                    data: "email"
                }             
            ]
        });
```

Here's the API code:

```
  // GET /api/members
    public IEnumerable<MemberDto> GetMembers(string query = null)
    {
        var membersQuery = _context.Members.ToList();

        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
            membersQuery = membersQuery.Where(c => c.FullName.Contains(query.ToUpper())).ToList();

        var memberDtos = membersQuery.ToList()
         .Select(Mapper.Map<Member, MemberDto>);

        return memberDtos;

    }
```

Comment: Can we see your "/api/members" method? Also, please check [this](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40690/sample-implementation-of-serverside-processing-in-c-mvc-ef-with-paging-sorting-searching) post for implementing serverSide datatables.

Comment: Where's your server-side processing?

Comment: please see my updated question.

Comment: @bangbang: Your server-side code is always returning all records.  Why exactly do you expect to see anything other than all records?  It looks like you simply forgot to implement your server-side processing.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to know. Can you point me to a tutorial where I can get an idea on how to implement it in C# MVC ?

Comment: @bangbang check link in my comment above